# MySQL Column (field) Max Width

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a MySQL table ('maxtesttable') full of user information (shortened here for demonstration purposes):

```
    SELECT * FROM maxtesttable;
    +-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
    | uid | firstname | lastname    | phone        |
    +-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
    |   1 | Abcdef    | Abcdefg     | 1234567      |
    |   2 | Abcd      | Abcde       | 123456789012 |
    |   3 | Abc       | Abcde-Fghij | 12345678     |
    |  14 | Abcd      | Abcdef      | 1234567890   |
    +-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to write an MySQL query that will return the maximum number of characters from each column (field).

With PHP, this is pretty straight-forward: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_fields.asp

However, I want to use it in a Python Script, and I'm hoping to get the answer from a MySQL query.

The results I'm expecting are:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| uid | firstname | lastname    | phone        |
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|   2 |         6 |          11 |           12 |
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

The longest "uid" in the result is "14" and it is 2 characters long.

The longest "firstname" in the result is "Abcdef" and it is 6 characters long.

The longest "lastname" in the result is "Abcde-Fghij" and it is 11 characters long.

The longest "phone" in the result is "123456789012" and it is 12 characters long.

Is there a straight-forward MySQL query that will give this result?  (or even a way in Python to evaluate the query result and get the same answer?)

There are some suggestions to use "max(char_length(columnname))" in MySQL, however, I'm not strong in MySQL and am looking for some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`MAX(LENGTH(columnname))` does exactly what you want.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(LENGTH(uid)) AS uid, 
    MAX(LENGTH(firstname)) AS firstname,
    MAX(LENGTH(lastname)) AS lastname,
    MAX(LENGTH(phone)) AS phone
FROM maxtesttable
```

The query is the same whether you're using Python or PHP to execute it.

Comment: I was stumbling all around that, and just completely messed up putting it all together.  Very simple, I completely missed it.  Thank you!